# predicting own image with model trained with MNIST dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I trained a model with the keras mnist dataset for handwriting digit recognition and it has an accuracy of 98%. But when it comes to my own image, the performance is poor. I suppose it has something to do with the preprocessing of my own image. 
here's how I try to convert the image to 28*28 size.

```
image = Image.open(f'screenshots/screenshot0.png').convert('L')
image = image.resize((28,28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
data = np.asarray(image)/255.0
```

And I found that the color of the image changes after the conversion

[here's the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmrEY.png)

[image after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxXF5.png)

You can see the white color turns gray after transformation, I wonder if this is the reason for the bad performance?

Comment: If the distribution of test data is different than the train data then model perform poorly. If you did data standardization on your train data and didn't do it on test data, then that can also affect models performance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used for training?

Answer (score 0):

Try using opencv for reading the image.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(f'screenshots/screenshot0.png',0)
image = cv2.resize(image, (28,28))
data = np.asarray(image)/255.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work, is there a way to scale the mnist dataset before training?